# R Services on SQL Server on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, amazon-rds, r

Can [R Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604845.aspx) be run on a SQLServer provisioned via [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/)?

Comment: Given that SSIS, SSAS, and SSRS aren't supported, my guess would be no. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

Comment: I found several references to running R services on AWS -- but all of them are discussing running the service on an EC2 machine. So yes, it looks like R Services is just like SSIS/SSAS/SSRS - Amazon's answer is "Just say no."